# What is the purpose of dot-decimal notation?

Tags: ip-address, ipv4

If all IPv4 addresses were always written as 12 digits long with no dots, that makes any ip address unambiguous and therefore still work.

For example 127.0.0.1 could be written as 127000000001

I feel this would make parsing and working with ip address easier. If this is the case, then what was the purpose behind the dot-decimal notation? What is the benefit of using dot-decimal notation?

Comment: Readability for _humans_ would be my first guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Research has shown humans can only read up to five digits without starting making errors in position of these digits. That's why humans start grouping numbers in thousands. For instance reading:

```
 1578124
```

is hard to parse fast. If we however represent it as:

```
1 578 124
```

It is way easier.

Especially if there are many digits with the same value like:

```
1000001101111000100001
```

one easily looses count.

The reason why they probably didn't want to use spaces is because most terminals interpret a space as new argument. So:

```
ping 127 0 0 1
connect: Invalid argument
```

Would be interpreted as four different arguments (hosts). Using dots makes it easy both for humans and machines.

But an IPv4 address consists out of four bytes (four numbers ranging from `0` to `255`). That's done so it can compactly get stored in four bytes in a network package. Nowadays that's of less importance because the bandwidth is that huge that four bytes take no time at all. But in the early days compression of addresses could save much time.

The same occurs for [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) addresses as well. Long sequences of zeros can be abbreviated with `::`.

Answer (score 4):

IP addresses *are* stored this way: e.g., "127.0.0.1" is actually 0x7F000001; there is no point to any third representation.

127,000,000,001 (one hundred twenty-seven billion and one) is more readable than 127000000001.

"127.0.0.1" is more readable than 0x7F000001.

"Hello World!" is more readable than 0x48656C6C6F20576F726C642100.

## Hello World!

is more readable than `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`.

Views are more readable than the Models they represent.

Our **primary job** as software developers is taking modeled data and presenting it as user content (or taking user input and modeling it as data): please don't take that away from us.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that dot-decimal notation was ambiguous. Just that there is an unambiguous way of representing an ip address without having to put dots in it.

Answer (score 3):

Each set of numbers in dot-decimal notation represents a byte in binary. For example:

```
127 -> 0111 1111
0 -> 0000 0000
1 -> 0000 0001
```

So 127.0.0.1 represents 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000001, as the computer sees it. 
If you were to treat this binary number as one big number, the actual decimal value of it would be 2130706433, which would then become your IP address if it wasn't for dot-decimal notation.
For obvious reasons, humans can remember 127.0.0.1 easier. Also, not using dot-decimal notation would mean you can't eliminate those leading zeroes that make it 127.0.0.1, not 127.000.000.001.